# Non-atomic measure on $\mathbb{Z}\cup\{\pm\infty\}$?

Tags: measure-theory

I have a rather naive question?

Is there a non-atomic measure on $\bar{Z}:=\mathbb{Z}\cup\{\pm\infty\}$?

For example, the counting measure is atomic.

Comment: obviously not since there are atoms only.

Comment: It's a countable set.

Comment: The answer to this question depends on the $\sigma$-algebra in question. You can avoid having the measure be atomic by not allowing atoms to be measurable.

Comment: @Elchanan Solomon That's clever, but can you give an example of a $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega=\mathbb{Z}\cup\{\pm\infty\}$ not having atoms?

Comment: I have posted a detailed answer to your question. Please, let me know if you have any question regarding my answer. If my answer provides relevant / helpful information regarding your question, please, upvote it. If my answer actualy answers your question, accept it too, please. To upvote, click the triangle **pointing upward above the number** (of votes) in front of the question. To accept the answer, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, there is no non-atomic measure on $\bar{Z}:=\mathbb{Z}\cup\{\pm\infty\}$, except for the identically null measure.

Let us prove it.

Recall that if $(X,\Sigma)$ is a measurable space, then $A\in \Sigma$ is an *atom in $\Sigma$* if and only if $A\neq \emptyset$ and for all $B\in \Sigma$ if $B \subseteq A$ then either $B=\emptyset$ or $B=A$.

Now let us prove the main result:

> Let $(X,\Sigma)$ be a measurable space. If $X$ is countable, then, for each $x \in X$, there is $A_x$, an atom  of $\Sigma$, such that $x\in A_x$

**Proof**:
Consider the the following relation defined in $X$:  $x\sim y$  if and only if, for all $E \in \Sigma$, if $x \in E$ then $y\in E$.

Claim: $\sim$ is an equivalence relation.

1. $x \sim x$.

It is trivial: for all $E \in \Sigma$, if $x \in E$ then $x\in E$.

2. if $x \sim y$ then   $y \sim x$ .

If $y \nsim x$ then there is $F \in \Sigma$ such that $y\in F$ and $x\notin F$. Let $E= F^c \in \Sigma$. Then $x\in E$ and $y\notin E$. So $x \nsim y$

3. if $x \sim y$ and $y \sim z$ the $x \sim z$

It is trivial: for all $E \in \Sigma$, if $x \in E$ then $y\in E$ and, for all $E \in \Sigma$, if $y \in E$ then $z\in E$. So, for all $E \in \Sigma$,  if $x \in E$ then $z\in E$.

This proves the claim.

Now, for each $x\in X$, for each $y\in X$, such that $y \nsim x$, take one $E_y \in \Sigma$ such that $x \in E_y$ and $y\notin E_y$.

Let us define $A_x=\bigcap_{y\in X} E_y$. Since $X$ is countable, we have that $A_x \in \Sigma$. We also have that $x\in A_x$.

It is easy to see that $A_x$ is an atom in $\Sigma$. In fact, since $x\in A_x$ so $A_x \neq \emptyset$. Now suppose that $A_x$ is not an atom in $\Sigma$, then there is $B\in \Sigma$ such that $B \subseteq A_x$, $B \neq \emptyset$ and $B \neq A_x$. Then there are $b, c \in A_x$, such that $b \in B$ and $c \notin B$.

If $x\in B$ then $x\nsim c$, so $A_x \subseteq E_c$ and $c\notin E_c$. So $c\notin A_x$. Contradiction.

If $x\notin B$ then $x \in B^c$ and $b \notin B^c$ so $x\nsim b$, so $A_x \subseteq E_b$ and $b\notin E_b$. So $b\notin A_x$. Contradiction.

So, we have proved that, for all $x\in X$, $A_x$ is an atom in $\Sigma$  and $x \in A_x$. $\square$

Our next result:

> Let $(X,\Sigma)$ be a measurable space. If $X$ is countable, then $\mu$ is non-atomic if and only if $\mu$ is identically zero.

**Proof**:

From the previous result, for all $x\in X$, $A_x$ is an atom in $\Sigma$  and $x \in A_x$.

The only way that an atom $A_x$ in $\Sigma$ will not become an atom of the measure is if $\mu(A_x)=0$.  So $\mu$ is non-atomic if and only if, for all $x\in X$, $\mu(A_x)=0$

But, clearly $X= \bigcup_{x\in X} A_x$  and this union is countable , because $X$ is countable. So

$$\mu(X)\leqslant \sum_{x\in X} \mu(A_x) = 0$$

So, $\mu$ is non-atomic if and only if $\mu$ is identically zero. $\square$

**Remark 1**: Using the fact that atoms of $\Sigma$ are disjoint, we can show that there is a partition of $X$ made of the atoms of $\Sigma$.

**Remark 2**: The result

> Let $(X,\Sigma)$ be a measurable space. If $X$ is countable, then, for each $x \in X$ there is $A_x$, an atom  of $\Sigma$, such that $x\in A_x$

can be proved using the Zorn lemma

**Proof**:
Let $\Gamma =\{ E \in \Sigma : x\in E \}$. Let us define the order $\leqslant$ in $\Gamma$ by $E \leqslant F$ if $F \subseteq E$. Suppose $\{E_\lambda\}_{\lambda \in L}$ be a totally ordered family of elements in $\Gamma$. Since $X$ is countable and $\{E_\lambda\}_{\lambda \in L}$ is a totally ordered, we have that $\{E_\lambda\}_{\lambda \in L}$ has only countable distinct elements.
So,
$$ E = \bigcap_{\lambda \in L} E_\lambda$$ is a countable intersection and so $E \in \Sigma$. $E$ is an upper bound of $\{E_\lambda\}_{\lambda \in L}$.

So, by Zorn lemma, there is $A_x \in \Gamma$ such that $A_x$ is a maximal element of $\Gamma$. Clearly, from the definition of $\Gamma$, $x \in A_x$

Now, $A_x$ is an atom of $\Sigma$. In fact, since $x \in A_x$, $A_x \neq \emptyset$. So, if $A_x$ is not an atom of $\Sigma$, there is $B\in \Sigma$ such that $B \subseteq A_x$, $B \neq \emptyset$ and $B \neq A_x$.

if $x \in B$, then $B \in \Gamma$ and $A_x \leqslant B$ and  $B \neq A_x$. Contradiction to the maximality of $A_x$ in $\Gamma$.

if $x \notin B$, then $x \in A_x \cap B^c$. So  $A_x \cap B^c \in \Gamma$ and $A_x \leqslant A_x \cap B^c$ and  $A_x \cap B^c \neq A_x$. Contradiction to the maximality of $A_x$ in $\Gamma$.

So $A_x$ is an atom of $\Sigma$ and $x \in A_x$.

Comment: @daw  Which $\sigma$-algebra?  $2^{\bar Z}$ ?  If so, the singletons would be atoms of the $\sigma$-algebra  and also atoms for the measure $\mu$ you are proposing. An atom may have infinite measure.